# Left touchpad button doesn't work on an eee pc 900

Tags: touchpad, eeepc

Left touchpad button doesn't work at all at my Asus eee pc 900 using Ubuntu 11.10. Have searched for the solution, found out that that's not only my problem, but haven't found a solution.

Is there anyone who solved this problem and can tell me how to do this?)

Answer (score -3):

See : http://www.fixya.com/support/t8657960-left_touchpad_button_not_working

Basically it says to:

> If you have an external mouse, try to insert that on your laptop.

All the rest from the link is Windows specific, but you can now attempt to change settings for your touch-pad.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: um, that is a solution for windows anyway...